# Swagger like description for RabbitMq .net core

Tags: .net, .net-core, rabbitmq, swagger-ui

we try to use rabbitmq for messaging, messages are small and currently there is not much different queues, as there will be many dirrefent companies which will integrate with us and amount of different queues will grow so maitaining actual description may become problem, so maybe there is some tool Like swagger for webapi which may help with that?
One possible solution is try to rewrite Swashbuckle and rewrite rabbitmq receiving part to be like webapi controllers, but not sure how much work will it take and i would like to avoid this way.

Or maybe i'm doit it incorrect way, but main idea is to have queue which will help resolve problems with performance as at some moments there migth be too many messages, and when message processing fails then message will remain in queue until problem is fixed, looks like rabbitmq is good enought for that but protocol description part is missing here

Answer (score 2):

Swagger is for RESTful APIs.  If you like the richer messaging semantics of RabbitMQ you can add something like:

- [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) (possibly with [gRPC](https://grpc.io/))
- [thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) (We're using this with ZeroMQ)